# .NET micro-benchmarking API

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, profiling, benchmarking

I'm looking for a library for doing micro-benchmarking of unit tests to monitor how code changes impact performance over time. That is, I would like the library to output results to e.g. XML to preserve history. It must be able to do this without any human assistant (i.e. run continously on our build server without too much hassle).

The library should be very simple and work on existing unit tests. Preferably I want to mark a test with a `[Benchmark]` attribute on the test I want to test or using a `using`-block, e.g.

```
using (var benchmarker = new Benchmarker())
{
  // Code to profile
} // Dispose() stores measurements.
```

Note that I'm not interrested in profiling tools as I programatically wan't to specify what parts of the code I want to profile. The library should be actively maintained.

I've had a look at [Jon Skeet's solution](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/01/26/benchmarking-made-easy/), but found it to be a bit too intrusive and [NTime](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/NTime.aspx) which has been dead for a few years.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the benchmarking project within Noda Time: http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/#hg%2Fsrc%2FNodaTime.Benchmarks

I don't think it's a good idea to use *existing* unit tests for benchmarking, personally... things which make good unit tests aren't necessarily good benchmark tests. In particular, an "expensive" assertion is entirely reasonable if you're only going to run it once per build, but you wouldn't want it to screw up the benchmark.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: true - I wasn't planning to add `[Benchmark]`-tags to all my existing test, but rather write benchmarking tests side by side with unit tests and optimally run them. The tests will only benchmark small parts of the code, not the integration. [QtTests  QBENCHMARK](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtestlib-manual.html#creating-a-benchmark) is close to what I'm looking for (but for C++).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Performance Profiler on unit tests, and save the results. Make your changes, and reprofile. There are more complex ways of doing it, but adding a new workflow is not always the best option.